# Finding a row-reduced echelon matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2& 1& 0\\ -1 &0 &3 &5\\  1& -2& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$.
I should find a row-reduced echelon matrix $R$ which is row equivalent to $A$ and an invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix $P$ such that $R = PA$.

I know that if a matrix is row equivalent to another that means that we can obtain such a matrix by using elementary row operations. But how should i apply this to such question?

Comment: Pambos thank you for editing ;))

Comment: The usual name for the process you need is _Gaussian elimination_. Chances are good that your textbook will have a longish explanation of it.

Comment: I know how I can use Gaussian elimination but how can I associate Gaussian elimination for finding P?

Answer (score 2):

This another approach, however; Don's way explains it to you in a brief solid form.

$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2& 1& 0\\ -1 &0 &3 &5\\  1& -2& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_1+R_2\mapsto R_2}\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2& 1& 0\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  1& -2& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}
\xrightarrow{-R_1+R_3\mapsto R_3}\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2& 1& 0\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  0& -4& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}\\\xrightarrow{-R_2+R_1\mapsto R_1}\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& -3& -5\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  0& -4& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{2R_2+R_3\mapsto R_3}\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& -3& -5\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  0& 0& 8& 11\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{\frac{-1}{2}R_3+R_2\mapsto R_2}\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& -3& -5\\ 0 &2 &0 &-0.5\\  0& 0& 8& 11\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{\frac{3}{8}R_3+R_1\mapsto R_1}\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& 0& \frac{-13}{8}\\ 0 &2 &0 &-0.5\\  0& 0& 8& 11\end{pmatrix}$

and the last matrix is the row-reduced echelon form of $A$.

Comment: ah thank you, as we talked above I'm going to apply these elementary row operations to the I matrix and get P1 from them

Answer (score 0):

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} \;1& 2& 1& 0\\ \!\!-1 &0 &3 &5\\  \;1& \!\!-2& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2+R_1\,,\,R_3-R1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix} \;1& 2& 1& 0\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  0& \!\!-4& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+2R_2}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} \;1& 2& 1& 0\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  0& 0& 8& 11\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, for example: to add 1st. row to 2nd one and to substract 1st. one from 3rd. one is to multiply $\,A\,$ from the left by matrix

$$P_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\\!\!\!-1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Take it from here, and show that each step you get an $invertible$ $\,3\times 3\,$ matrix, so at the end $\,P\,$ is a product of these matrices and, thus, an invertible one.

**Added:** Thus,

$$P_1A=\begin{pmatrix} \;1& 2& 1& 0\\ 0 &2 &4 &5\\  0& \!\!-4& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

which is the middle matrix above.

Now you try to generalize the above to ge the matrix $\,P_2\,$ s.t. $\,P_2P_1A\,$ gives us the rightmost matrix above (the already reduced form)

Comment: Pardon me but I could not understand "Take it from here, and show that each step you get an invertible 3×3 matrix"

Comment: And also I could not understand how you go [1 0 0; 1 1 0; -1 0 1] matrix by using only 3 elementary row operation ..

Comment: @YigitCan, I'm going to add some info to my answer, which I thought was already clear.

Comment: Do you agree with me that explaining such this problem here while we don't have any interactive action with the OP is a bit hard?

Comment: Oh @DonAntonio I see what you have already explained. So you're saying that we apply each elementary row operations to the I matrix and find P1 and keep going in this way? And P is equal the product of P1 P2 and P3, did I get it right?

Comment: Yes...and if you need more elementary row operations you keep on multiplying *from the left* what you already did. It is exactly the same with elementary *column* operations but then we multiply from the right.

Comment: Oh yes i understand it, so can we conclude that the P is equal to the product of matrices where I found them from applying the elementary row operations?